# JavaScript is returning a repeating decimal

Tags: javascript, precision

This array reduce line is the code I use to get a total.

```
let arr = [{c:25,q:1},{c:23.99,q:1},{c:32,q:1}];

let chg = arr.reduce((tot,b) => {return tot+b.c*b.q;},0);
```

I attempt to convert it to cents as per stripe with this code.

```
parseFloat(chg.toFixed(2)) * 100
```

And I get this! **8098.999999999999**

WTF  ‍♂️

I provided an example.

```js
let arr = [{c:25,q:1},{c:23.99,q:1},{c:32,q:1}];


let chg = arr.reduce((tot,b) => {return tot+b.c*b.q;},0);

console.log(chg);
console.log(parseFloat(chg.toFixed(2)));
console.log(chg.toFixed(2))

console.log(parseFloat(chg.toFixed(2))*100)
console.log(parseFloat("80.99")*100)
console.log((80.99)*100)
```

Why is JavaScript returning a repeating decimal??

Comment: It's a floating point rounding error, see: https://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript